# cant put text object back on xib when moved off view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xib

This may sound very basic but I've only used xcode with storyboards, ive moved a text box off a xib,  now I want to put it back on the view its surrounded by a box with a x in the top left and wont go back on the view, what basic step am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to place an OSX object in the iOS environment. Make sure you have the correct library selected.